# Java derived class not automatically creating instance

Tags: java, logging, abstract, derived

I have a base abstract logger class, that has an instance variable that I want to be set by the derived class automatically when the code is create. So here is the base class:

```
abstract public class CLog 
{
    /** Maintains the call stack level for each thread */
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> callStackLevel = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    /** Static instance to be set by the derived class */
    private static CLog instance = null;

    /** Logs in verbose */
    public static void v(String message) { if(instance != null) instance.verbose(getMessage(message)); }
    /** Logs in debug */
    public static void d(String message) { if(instance != null) instance.debug(getMessage(message)); }
    /** Logs in informational */
    public static void i(String message) { if(instance != null) instance.info(getMessage(message)); }
    /** Logs in warning */
    public static void w(String message) { if(instance != null) instance.warn(getMessage(message)); }
    /** Logs in error */
    public static void e(String message) { if(instance != null) instance.error(getMessage(message)); }

    /**
     * Calculates the message (with header)
     */
    private static String getMessage(String message)
    {
        ...
    }

    /** Constructor sets instance */
    protected CLog() { instance = this; }

    /** Logs in verbose */
    protected abstract void verbose(String message);
    /** Logs in debug */
    protected abstract void debug(String message);
    /** Logs in informational */
    protected abstract void info(String message);
    /** Logs in warning */
    protected abstract void warn(String message);
    /** Logs in error */
    protected abstract void error(String message);
}
```

I creates the derived class for an android logger. I want it to automatically call the constructor, but it seems this isn't working because nothing is resulting from all my logging functions.

```
public class AndroidLog extends CLog 
{
    protected static AndroidLog derived = new AndroidLog();

    @Override
    protected void debug(String message) {
        Log.d("Crystal", message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void error(String message) {
        Log.e("Crystal", message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void info(String message) {
        Log.i("Crystal", message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void verbose(String message) {
        Log.v("Crystal", message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void warn(String message) {
        Log.w("Crystal", message);
    }
}
```

Why is this not working? When I call the static function in the base class, I am not getting any logs.

Is there anyway by just editting the AndroidLog class or by making an edit in the CLog class that isn't dependent on AndroidLog to make this work?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do. Do you reference `AndroidLog` anywhere? If not, then it won't be loaded and thus the constructor never called: the pure existance of a class does **not** cause it to be loaded, it needs to be referenced somewhere.

Comment: Where and how is the `Log` symbol defined, and the object assigned to it created?

Comment: @Joachim So even though I have declared a static variable in the derived class and set equal to an instance of the class, it won't be created unless referenced outside of the class?

Comment: @T.J. Android Log: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: @gamernb: that's right: if nothing in your app points at that class, then there's nothing that indicates it should be loaded (and its static fields initialized). The class can't bootstrap itself.

Comment: @gamemb: Thanks. Haven't done any Android dev yet, thought it might have been an instance of `CLog` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mere existence of the `AndroidLog` class won't cause it to bootstrap itself!

In Java classes are loaded and initialized when they are used, not before! So unless any class of yours somewhere references `AndroidLog` in some relevant way, it will never be loaded, it's static fields never initialized and its constructor will never be called.

Comment: @gamermb: You can force it to load, though: `Class c = Class.forName("AndroidLog");` That will tell the JVM that you need it to load the class, which will perform a static init on it. But I'm having trouble seeing how you're calling it if you never reference it. I don't see any code in the constructor that hooks into some logging framework or some such (which is the usual reason you have to play `Class.forName` games).

Comment: The base class constructor sets the instance variable. So all I require is a derived class to be instantiated, thus calling the base constructor.

Comment: I'm confused about Class.forName(). How does it work, and where exactly would I put the function call?

Answer (score 0):

Another important aspect is the fact that private static class members are not inherited! Your AndroidLog class will not have access to any of the private static members in the base class.

Comment: I don't care. The whole point is that I want all my classes to log using the Base class static variables, that use the instance of what ever current logger is loaded.